# Drawing Lines Over Pre-Existing Image Cause Color Error - PHP

Tags: php, imagecreatefrompng

I am trying to take the image of a map and am trying to draw red, white, and blue lines on top of the image. I am able to import the map image and draw lines, but the lines print out as black, instead of their specified colors. If I remove the `imagecreatefrompng` part the lines appear with the proper colors.

map.png is a local copy of: [image: this Image]

Here is my code that is causing issues.

```
header("Content-type:image/png");

$img=imagecreate(800, 495);

$black_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
$white_color=imagecolorallocate($img,255,255,255);
$red_color=imagecolorallocate($img,255,0,0);
$blue_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,255);
$clear_color=imagecolorallocatealpha($img,0,0,0,0);

$img = imagecreatefrompng('map.png');

imageline($img,550,162,100,200,$red_color);
imageline($img,550,162,200,200,$blue_color);
imageline($img,550,162,300,200,$white_color);


return (imagepng($img));
```

I greatly appreciate any help that could be provided to get the colors to show up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I moved your line:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('map.png');
```

up to right below:

```
$img=imagecreate(800, 495);
```

and it worked for me.